# The code below doesn't compile. Maybe because GCC with std=c++2a is still not completely up to date with the most recent draft

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

[[class.mem]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6):

> A *complete-class context* of a class is a
>
> (6.1) function body,     (6.2) default argument,     (6.3)
>   *noexcept-specifier* ([except.spec]),     (6.4) contract condition, or     (6.5) default member initializer
>
> within the *member-specification* of the class. [ Note: A
>   complete-class context of a nested class is also a complete-class
>   context of any enclosing class, if the nested class is defined within
>   the *member-specification* of the enclosing class. — end note ]

This paragraph was introduced in the draft with pull-request [#2231](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2231/commits/01290e16af741f3b317f0930bc6cf52dbdbd1777).

As far as I can understand, the following code should compile, according to the Note above. But [it doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gQIXwi7Zj3lDhhDV#result-container-tab-permlink). I'm assuming that the GCC compiler is still not up to date with the most recent draft. Am I correct, or is it the case that my understanding about this note is incorrect?

```
struct A {
    int i = 1;
    struct B { 
        int j = 2;
        int f() {
            return i + j;
        }
    };
};
```

Which fails with:

```
source>: In member function 'int A::B::f()':
<source>:6:20: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::i'
    6 |             return i + j;
      |                    ^
<source>:2:9: note: declared here
    2 |     int i = 1;
      |         ^
```

Comment: What do you expect `i` to refer to in that expression? And what new aspect of C++20 do you consider to have changed in a relevant way?

Comment: Which version of g++ exactly?

Comment: @Barry The note seems to tell me that it refers to `A::i`, or not?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See the link to WandBox above.

Comment: No, it shouldn't compile. The quoted passage has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @WaldB It's generally better to mention that in your question (keep it self contained) instead of relying on the link.

Comment: @n.m. Then what exactly is that note saying?

Comment: @WaldB: You are trying to access a non-static data member from a class which is *not* the class it is a member of. That *never works*. Just ask yourself a question: which `A` object will the `i` come from? After all, there's no requirement that you ever create an instance of `A`; you can create an `A::B` without ever creating an `A`.

Comment: The note clarifies which names are visible where and what they refer to. It doesn't suddenly make a visible name valid to use in every way you want.

Comment: Think of it the other way around if that helps: Which non-static `A::i` would `B` refer too? Different `A`'s  can create a lot of `B`:s and pass them around.

Comment: You could define a class `X` which cannot be constructed at all (say all ctors are delete) yet declares data members (which are never going to come into existence). But a class declared with a nested name (`X::Y`) could be constructed.

Comment: `B::f`'s function-body is a complete-class context of class `B` and so of class `A` (according to the Note). But that doesn't allow you to access a non-static data member of `A` in `B::f()`, and this is due to [\[expr.prim.id\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the confusion stems here from what the point of *complete-class context* is and how is it intended to be used.

Importantly, name lookup will find `i` there. So I can write this:

```
struct A {
    struct B { 
        int j = 2;
        int f() {
            using T = decltype(i); // ok, even though 'i' declared later lexically
            return T{} + j;        // ok
        }
    };
    int i = 1;
};
```

As well as:

```
struct A {
    struct B { 
        int j = 2;
        int f() {
            return i + j; // ok, even though 'i' declared later lexically
        }
    };
    static const int i = 1;
};
```

Indeed, this was ok all the way back in C++11.

But `i` is still a non-static member, so you can only access it from the context of an object of type `A`. Within the body of a member function of `B`, we don't implicitly have an `A` object. So such a free use of `i` is still ill-formed.

---

That said, this:

> I'm assuming that the GCC compiler is still not up to date with the most recent draft.

Is certainly true, and will remain true for quite some time.

Comment: Then, what is the meaning of the note in [class.mem]/6?

Comment: @WaldB The note means `using T = decltype(i);` is legal.  `return i + j;` though can't be legal because you don't have an `A` object to access `i` from.

Comment: @WaldB It means what it says it means - nested complete class contexts are also complete class contexts of their enclosing classes. So in `B::f()` both `B` and `A` are complete. That doesn't let you just use non-static data members - think about what that would even mean.

Comment: @Barry `So in B::f() both B and A are complete.` That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: This example isn't really exercising the "complete-class context" part though. Moving `i` and `j`'s declarations to the end of their respective class might make the point clearer.

Answer (score 2):

> Then what exactly is that note saying?

Names declared within the class `A` are in scope within the complete-class context even if before the point of declaration of the name.

The note means that the complete-class context of the enclosing class (noting the pre-condition) extends to the complete-class context of the nested class.

Therefore following is well-formed:

```
struct A {
    struct B{
        void foo() {
            // names are in scope despite being before point of declaration
            I i;
            var;
        }
    };

     using I = int;
     static int var;
};
```

You cannot access a non-static data member in a (non-static) member function of another class just like you cannot access non-static members in a static member function of the same class. Complete-class context does not change that.